# Review Queue - Posts awaiting review

Tags: support, review-queue

So having reached 10k yesterday, that triggers the next privilege of accessing the mod tools. As a result, there is now the little orange number on the top bar next to the review button. This used to (pre 10k) just show when there were edits pending but now shows up when anything is pending. Makes sense.

But I have a question. What does that number represent? For example, I've just been through the queues and whatnot and they are now empty as far as I can see, but yet the number of posts pending review shows 15:

[image: Pending or not?]

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

---

<sup>p.s. I have refreshed the page and it is still there</sup>

Comment: The orange number is a *rough* indicator of the total amount of review tasks in the queues.  It's not updated in real time.  It lags the actual number.  There is a discussion somewhere in our meta about this discrepancy; maybe I can find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The orange indicator shows the (approximate) number of tasks awaiting a review.

The review page shows the number of tasks awaiting **your** review. This excludes the items you are not eligible to review: because you flagged the post, or voted to close it, or have reviewed it already, etc.

It's a pretty expensive process to identify which of the review tasks you are eligible for. So this is not done for the orange indicator, which is shown on every page load (SE has a lot of page loads...). In addition, the number it shows is cached.

Reference: [Review counts in top-bar and /review don't match](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233535/review-counts-in-top-bar-and-review-dont-match)